# Elliptic Curve Diffie-Hellman Symmetric Keys Not Matching On Client and Server

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl, elliptic-curve

I'm using JCSL - Javascript on client [(documentation)](http://bitwiseshiftleft.github.io/sjcl/doc/) and OpenSSL - Ruby on server [(documentation)](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/PKey/EC.html) to generate a symmetric key on both client and server using Elliptic Curve Diffie-Hellman.

I've somehow finally managed to format properly the public keys to be sent by the Client and Server, and I've finally generated a symmetric key without anymore runtime errors [(my previous question)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22325272/how-to-use-elliptic-curves-diffie-hellman-with-sjcl-in-js-and-openssl-in-ruby)

However, the problem now is that `Client's Symmetric Key != Server's Symmetric Key`

I feel that it would be best if you could try this out on your computer, so I thought of uploading the compiled JS file from JCSL (this includes the Elliptic Curve) for testing convenience [(link)](http://www.mediafire.com/view/b8703rivopzc5d6/sjcl.js)

My Code as follows (you can just copy-paste this for testing convenience):

```
#Ruby on Rails
class EcdhController < ApplicationController

  @@group = OpenSSL::PKey::EC::Group.new('secp384r1')
  @@ec = OpenSSL::PKey::EC.new(@@group)

  def connect
    logger.info('CONNECT PAGE:::::::::::::::::')
  end

  def send_params
    logger.info('SEND_PARAMS::::::::::::::::::')

    #GENERATE PUBLIC AND PRIVATE KEYS
    @@ec.generate_key

    #SEND PUBLIC KEY TO CLIENT/BROWSER
    #[2..-1] means I've removed the first two Hex characters which is x04 which I think is automatically prepended by OpenSSL which causes errors in the Client JS side
    render :json => {:server_pub_key => @@ec.public_key.to_bn.to_s(16)[2..-1]}
  end

  def receive_client_pub_key
    logger.info('RECEIVE_CLIENT_PUB_KEY:::::::::::::::')

    #Convert properly the format of the JCSL pub key on client side
    client_pub_key = (params[:client_pub_key].split(",").map { |s| s.to_i }).pack('N*')

    #Copied from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135420/elliptic-curve-cryptography-with-sjcl-in-js-and-openssl-in-ruby
    algokey = OpenSSL::ASN1::ObjectId 'id-ecPublicKey'
    algovalue = OpenSSL::ASN1::ObjectId 'secp384r1'
    algo = OpenSSL::ASN1::Sequence.new [algokey,algovalue]
    # for some reason OpenSSL seems to prepend 0x04 to all public keys
    key = OpenSSL::ASN1::BitString.new "\x04#{client_pub_key}"
    root = OpenSSL::ASN1::Sequence.new [algo,key]

    pub = OpenSSL::PKey.read(root.to_der)
    #-End of copied code-#

    #COMPUTE SYMMETRIC KEY
    symm_key = @@ec.dh_compute_key(pub.public_key)

    puts "SYMM KEY: #{symm_key.unpack('H*').first}"

    #---> SYMM KEY: f8de0a7012765a1ff8b7630c917a1d3d2ac9cc0d782fbb6c0c101128a29232fec5194468b7ed846053abab05744c61e9    

    render :json => nil
  end
end
```

While on Client Side,

```
//Javascript
<h1>Ecdh#connect</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/ecdh/connect.html.erb</p>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        var server_pub_key;
        var client_priv_key;
        var client_pub_key;

        connect();

        function connect()
        {
            //Receive Server Public Key
            jQuery.getJSON('<%= url_for(:controller => :ecdh, :action => :send_params) %>', function(data)
            {
                //Get Server Public Key
                server_pub_key_Bits = new sjcl.bn(data.server_pub_key.toString()).toBits(); //Convert Hex String to BN, and then to Bits

                //Client Keys
                client_keys = sjcl.ecc.elGamal.generateKeys(384, 0);
                client_keys.generate_keys;

                client_pub_key_Hex = sjcl.bn.fromBits( client_keys.pub.serialize().point ).toString(16); //Into bits, then to Hex
                client_priv_key = client_keys.sec; //sjcl.ecc.elGamal.privateKey format

                //Send Client/Own Public Key to Server
                jQuery.getJSON('<%= url_for(:controller => :ecdh, :action => :receive_client_pub_key) %>?client_pub_key='+client_keys.pub.serialize().point, function()
                {
                    //Set Curve from Template
                    curve = sjcl.ecc.curves['c384'];

                    //Convert server_pub_key_Bits to proper 'publicKey' format
                    server_pub_key = new sjcl.ecc.elGamal.publicKey(384, curve, server_pub_key_Bits);

                    //Compute Shared Key
                    symm_key_Bits = client_priv_key.dh(server_pub_key);
                    symm_key_Hex = sjcl.bn.fromBits(symm_key_Bits).toString(16);

                    console.log(symm_key_Hex);

                    //---> 0xa779359617b008884b67c0785a3f782b9dca6e46f9586f7e911b73de877f2aca
                }); 
            }); 
        }
    }); 
</script>
```

Thus my problem is

```
f8de0a7012765a1ff8b7630c917a1d3d2ac9cc0d782fbb6c0c101128a29232fec5194468b7ed846053abab05744c61e9
!=
0xa779359617b008884b67c0785a3f782b9dca6e46f9586f7e911b73de877f2aca
```

Feel free to ask me how to convert format and stuff if you want to test or anything, as this is vital for my project. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've finally solved this problem :)

I am now using JSBN-EC [(link)](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~tjw/jsbn/) rather than JCSL on Javascript-client.

Refer to [(this)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22483036/why-is-the-ecc-dh-symmetric-key-of-this-site-different-from-openssl) another question of mine for more details